# How to programmatically rename a file containing decomposed characters?

Tags: unicode, vbscript, utf

I occasionnaly have to deal with files produced in a Mac environment, and with filenames containing decomposed characters (looks like "é", but really is "e´"). Those are visibly not recognized by Scripting.FileSystemObject and therefore cannot be acted on. I need to programmatically rename those files to remove the decomposed characters before further processing.

From what I found : "é (U+00E9) is a character that can be decomposed into an equivalent string of the base letter e (U+0065) and combining acute accent (U+0301)."

In other words, both strings look exactly like this : "é", but the length of the first one is 1 and the length of the second one is 2. If converted, it actually looks like this "e´".

Here's a little script for testing purposes :

(Please create those two test files by copy/pasting the names)
Filename with composed character (working) : é.txt

Filename with decomposed character (not working) : é.txt

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
For Each Arg in Wscript.Arguments 

Set objFile = FSO.GetFile(Arg)
fPath = Left(objFile.Path, Len(objFile.Path)-Len(objFile.Name))

FSO.movefile arg, fpath & "a.txt"
Set objFile = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

next
```

The file with the decomposed character produces a "File not found" error. 
I managed to convert a string from decomposed to composed characters, but still not working when trying to rename an actual file.

I'm completely stuck at this point, and any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't run into this issue with FSO but only because I've never dealt with files named like that. Taking your statement *"hose are visibly not recognized by Scripting.FileSystemObject and therefore cannot be acted on."* at face value, then I don't see how you could use `FSO` to rename the file with `FSO.movefile arg, fpath & "a.txt"` Surely you would have to use a different utility that can handle the different filename.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right, FSO is useless in this case. To avoid using it, I tried to rename the same file using PowerShell, then using VBA. In both cases, I still get the same ''File not found'' error.It does work using third party software (namely AntRenamer) but, for the actual purpose, it needs to be done trough scripting.

Comment: When you do the renaming through powershell, what happens? Does the file get renamed, or do you get a different error?

Comment: This is what I get with PowerShell : + Rename-Item <<<<  C:\__Work\docp\e´.txt C:\__Work\docp\a.txt 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the VBS/WSH `DropHandler` `(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx\DropHandler)`

The DropHandler of VBS/WSH files is `{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}`.
EXE/BAT/CMD files are handled by `{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}`.

VBS/WSH drophandler parses the dropped object(s) to a long file path while the EXE/BAT/CMD drophandler parses the dropped object(s) to short file path (such as C:\PROGRA~1).

The problem is that the DropHandler of VBS doesn't parse the dropped object in Unicode way.

Your code is relying on items being dropped apparently so you rely on the `WScript.Arguments`.

The FSO functions CAN handle filenames like you describe.
You can test this by performing a

```
Set objFile = FSO.GetFile("<PATH>\e´.txt")`
```

or even

```
FSO.FileExists("<PATH>\e´.txt")
```

However, coming in through the arguments, the filenames are already crippled by the drophandler. I see no safe way of changing this behaviour other than messing around in the Windows Registry or by changing your script to not use 'drag-'n-drop' but getting the filenames from the OpenFile dialog perhaps.

Comment: You stated that FSO functions CAN handle those filenames. I was falsely assuming otherwise, since all my FSO tests failed (including those you cite as examples). It made me think something else was wrong, and I finally found it. My VBS file was saved by default in AINSI format, and I had to save it in Unicode. There's probably something else that I don't understand, beacuse it still doesn't work in PowerShell or in VBA. Yet, the script I wanted to work is working, and it's good enough for me. I will mark your post as the answer, since you really put me on the right track.

Comment: For those who may encounter similar issues, here's the working version of the test script from my original post:

`Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
For Each Arg in Wscript.Arguments 

Arg = Replace(Arg, "e´", "é")

Set objFile = FSO.GetFile(Arg)
fPath = Left(objFile.Path, Len(objFile.Path)-Len(objFile.Name))

FSO.movefile arg, fpath & Replace(objFile.name, "é", "a")

Set objFile = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

next`

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I noticed someone edited my answer, but made a mistake in the second example (`FSO.FileExists("<PATH>\e´.txt")`). I have re-edited it as it was supposed to be . Anyway, glad you've fixed it now.